# How to make a container take the same amount of space that its content takes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/cje0nuq1/

HTML

```
<form action="" class="form">
                <div class="form-input-wrap">
                    <div class="form__header">Leave a review</div>
                    <div class="input-area">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="text-input"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --first-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    --second-color: rgb(255, 102, 102);
    --third-color: rgb(255, 74, 74);
}
.form {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: var(--first-color);
    color: #000;
    padding: 5%;
    border: thin solid #ccc;
}
.form__header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: var(--third-color);
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.form-input-wrap {
    width: 60%;
}
.input-area {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: thin solid #ccc;
    width: auto;
}
.input-area label {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--third-color);
}
.input-area input {
    border: thin solid #ccc;
    height: 22px;
}
.input-area input:focus {
    outline: none!important;
}
.text-input {
    resize: none;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.text-input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.form input[type="submit"] {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: var(--third-color);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: darkred;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

How to make .input-area container take the exact same amount of space that its childs take?

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, thank you. I've already found out this. And it's supported in more browsers than width: fit-content

Answer (score 2):

Apply `width:fit-content`:

```css
.form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: var(--first-color);
  color: #000;
  padding: 5%;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}

.form__header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: var(--third-color);
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-input-wrap {
  width: 60%;
}

.input-area {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: thin solid #ccc;
  width: fit-content;
}

.input-area label {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--third-color);
}

.input-area input {
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  height: 22px;
}

.input-area input:focus {
  outline: none!important;
}

.text-input {
  resize: none;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.text-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: var(--third-color);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
  <div class="form-input-wrap">
    <div class="form__header">Leave a review</div>
    <div class="input-area">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <textarea class="text-input"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Comment: for firefox,  max-content works , fit-content seems not.

Answer (score 0):

to include Firefox, i would use `max-content`instead `fit-content` in place `width:auto;`that you have set for `.input-area`.

```css
.form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: var(--first-color);
  color: #000;
  padding: 5%;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}

.form__header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: var(--third-color);
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-input-wrap {
  width: 60%;
}

.input-area {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: thin solid #ccc;
  width:max-content;
}

.input-area label {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--third-color);
}

.input-area input {
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  height: 22px;
}

.input-area input:focus {
  outline: none!important;
}

.text-input {
  resize: none;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.text-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: var(--third-color);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
  <div class="form-input-wrap">
    <div class="form__header">Leave a review</div>
    <div class="input-area">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <textarea class="text-input"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```